# android delete app not working

Tags: java, android, root

I granted superuser permission on a rooted phone, however, if I fire then an intent to remove desired app, still working only for apps that are not on system but for system apps generates a message saying that app was not uninstalled properly. How to reach it?

```
                        Process process; 
                        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");


                        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /system/\n");  
                       os.flush();  

                        Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED); //ACTION_DELETE
                        uninstallIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + llistaApps.get(idApp)));
                        uninstallIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                        uninstallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) superuser permission does nothing to the app itself, it only lets it launch native helper executables as root

2) it does not enable any android permissions, as it is a concept that functions at the linux rather than android level, and also because it does not apply to the app itself.

3) this question has numerous duplicates

Comment: well, so how to get permission to erase system app?

Comment: Either try to get installed as a system app (which is a different question, with duplicates) or be crude and use `rm` under `su` which also has many duplicates.  Neither is really something someone inexperienced should be attempting.